# how can we delete certain option from an drop down attribute(magento)

Tags: magento

I need to delete certain option value from an attribute, for example `color`. If `color` has red, blue and green as options, then I need to delete one of them, for example blue.

I have so far been able to get the attribute values but I am having problems deleting a particular option.

```
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'color_pattern');
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);
```

How can I delete an option from the list of options? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanking you,

Comment: Just to be clear, you *need* to do this programmatically, and cannot do it through the admin tool?

Comment: or the database, for that matter...

Comment: ya , i have been successful in inserting certain option value in an attribute while a file is uploaded automatically , but couldnt seem to find any function  to delete the option value from the attribute while the file is deleted , any ways i found a way to delete it through sql query.. thanx anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

found another way:

```
$options['delete'][$option_id] = true; 
$options['value'][$option_id] = true;

$options['delete'][$another_option_id] = true; 
$options['value'][$another_option_id] = true;

// (...)

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($options);
```

cheers, johannes

Answer (score 0):

found a way to delete options through sql statement ;)

```
if (@unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "sizecharts" . DS . $sizecharts->getFilename())) {

    $select = $read->select()
            ->distinct(true)
            ->from($optionvalueTable, array('option_id'))
            ->where('value="' . $sizecharts->getFilename() . '"');

    $opt1 = $read->fetchAll($select);
    $deleteCondition = $write->quoteInto('option_id=?', $opt1[0]['option_id']);
    $write->delete($optionTable, $deleteCondition);
    //$model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
    $sizecharts->delete();
}
```